# В PHPSTORM при работе с html в php файле высвечивается зеленая полоса при пробеле

Tags: php, javascript, css3, html5, phpstorm

Как убрать или отключить вон ту зеленое выделение?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил. Заходим в  **Settings | Editor | Language Injections** и отключите все инжекшены с IDE scope (все, которые не Built-in)